# AWS Rekognition - create image from detect-faces bounding box

Tags: aws-lambda, face-detection, amazon-rekognition

Currently trying to figure out how to make face crops from bounding boxes (from detect-faces response) and use those crops to search an existing collection using the SearchFacesByImage API

This is mentioned on the SearchFacesByImage documentation.

> You can also call the DetectFaces operation and use the bounding boxes in the response to make face crops, which then you can pass in to theSearchFacesByImage operation

I am trying to do this in Python or Node.js in a Lambda function. The input image is an s3 object.

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to do this in java but so far unable to complete it because of a problem in converting the AWS Image to java Image. I have some code in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801592/aws-image-getbytes-returning-null

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the exact same problem. Refer [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/images-orientation.html) from AWS Documentation. Here you will find sample code for python or java both. It will return the Top, Lfet, Width and Height of the bounding box. Remember, the upper-left corner will be considered as (0,0).

Then if you use python, you can crop image with cv2 or PIL.

Here is an example with PIL:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open( 'my_image.png' )
cropped = img.crop( ( Left, Top, Left + Width, Top + Height ) ) 
cropped.show()
```

In this code Top, Lfet, Width and Height is a response from code given in the link.

Answer (score 0):

I did this script in java, maybe its help

```
        java.awt.image.BufferedImage image = ...
    com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.BoundingBox target ...


    int x = (int) Math.abs((image.getWidth() * target.getLeft()));
    int y = (int) Math.abs((image.getHeight() *target.getTop()));;
    int w = (int) Math.abs((image.getWidth() * target.getWidth()));
    int h = (int) Math.abs((image.getHeight() * target.getHeight()));

    int finalX = x + w;
    int finalH = y + h;

    if (finalX > image.getWidth())
        w = image.getWidth()-x;

    if (finalH > image.getHeight())
        h = image.getHeight()-y;


    System.out.println(finalX);
    System.out.println(finalH);

    //
    //
    BufferedImage subImage = image.getSubimage(
            x, 
            y, 
            w,
            h);

    //
    //
    String base64 = ImageUtils.imgToBase64String(subImage, "jpg");
```