# AWS Image getBytes returning null

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, amazon-rekognition

I am trying to convert and `AWS Rekognition Image` to java `BufferedImage`. In order to do this I need the byte array from the AWS Image. However, when I call the `getBytes` method it returns null instead of returning `ByteBuffer`. My code is as below:

```
    //Load an Rekognition Image object from S3
    Image inputImage = new Image()
            .withS3Object(new com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.S3Object().withName(key).withBucket(bucket));

    DetectFacesRequest request = new DetectFacesRequest().withImage(inputImage).withAttributes(Attribute.ALL);

    try {
        DetectFacesResult result = amazonRekognition.detectFaces(request);
        List<FaceDetail> faceDetails = result.getFaceDetails();
        System.out.println("Number of faces: " + faceDetails.size());
        int count = 1;

        // I do get a number of FaceDetails back which proves that I am reading the image correctly from S3
        for (FaceDetail faceDetail : faceDetails) {
          BoundingBox faceBox = faceDetail.getBoundingBox();
            try {

                 // Load image
                  ByteBuffer imageBytes=inputImage.getBytes();
                  if (imageBytes == null) {
                      System.out.println("Why is this null?");
                      return false;
                  }
     ...
```

The input image is only 80KB in size, not sure if size matters.

Comment: Are you talking about `inputImage.getBytes()`? Aren't you setting it in the first line of code? In fact, what do you mean by "AWS Rekognition Image"?

Comment: Yes I am talking about this method. I am loading the image using `withS3Object` but when I call the `getBytes` method I get null

Comment: Have you checked whether the first line of your code is actually loading the object successfully?

Comment: Pls see my comment just above the for loop. I am able to run face detection on the image.